# Upgraded Capybara 2 and all my has_selector tests broke

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

I upgraded to Rails 3.2 and Capybara 2.1 and about 30% of my 700 tests are failing. A bunch of the failed tests are like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe BooksController do
  render_views
  let(:page)  { Capybara::Node::Simple.new(@response.body) }

      describe "new" do

        it "should get new" do
          get :new, :author_id => author_token, :publish_action => "Publish"
          response.should be_success
          page.should have_selector "h1", text:"Transition" 
        end
   end
 end
```

The failed test output is:

```
BooksController should get new content
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector 'h1', text:'Preview'
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "h1" with text "Preview" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/controllers/books_controller_spec.rb:46:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I use print page.html, save_and_open_page, etc., I get a blank or no output. But a lot of the other tests pass. It seems to be something related to checking the h1 tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out rspec-rails docs under the [Upgrading to Capybara 2](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/Capybara.md) section. I grant you this information is somewhat hidden and took me a while to find.

Basically, In order to use the Capybara DSL(page & visit) you must move your specs into the `spec/features` directory. So you can only use `page & visit` in acceptance tests. No more page & visit in controller specs. Only the rack-test DSL `(get|post|put|delete|head/response.body)` is allowed in controller specs.

This is **not** recommended but there is a way to keep your specs working as they are:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Capybara::DSL, :example_group => {
    :file_path => "spec/requests"
  }
end
```

The docs state that if you go this route then you are overriding the intended behavior and you are taking a risk.

Hope this gets you on the right path

Comment: Thanks. This is my problem and I did not see that documentation before. Now to move the tests over!

Comment: +1 No problem. I saw this was an unanswered question from a while back and was not sure if you had figured it out. glad to help.